# Nested rows with Jetpack Compose FlowRow

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Can we have nested rows in the FlowRow? I'm trying to render a grid of items with various sizes and expect that they can fill the space if it's size fit.

For e.g, with following screenshot, how can I make the `Phone` and `Calendar` to be displayed right below `Zoom` and `Messages` ?

```
FlowRow(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth(1f)
        .wrapContentHeight(align = Alignment.Top)
        .wrapContentSize(Alignment.CenterStart)
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
) {
 //items here
}
```

[image]

Comment: are tried `LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid` example - https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/staggeredgrid/package-summary#LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.staggeredgrid.StaggeredGridCells,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.staggeredgrid.LazyStaggeredGridState,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Horizontal,androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.FlingBehavior,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1)

Comment: I tried LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid before, but it leads to another issue, the items are arranged into columns with the same width,